# Is it possible to not escape double quotes and get the right json format?

Tags: bash, shell, quoting, json

I want to submit json data using httpie.

If I use double quotes and escape the double quotes surrounding the key, it works.

```
json="[ \
    { \
        \"count\": 3 \
    } \
]"
```

`echo $json`

[ { "count": 3 } ]

But I don't want to escape. The following is easier to copy and paste, but it does not work.

```
json='[ \
    { \
        "count": 3 \
    } \
]'
```

`echo $json`

[ \ { \ "count": 3 \ } \ ]

So, is it possible to not escape the double quotes surrounding the json key, make it easier to copy from somewhere and paste?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no need for backslashes to continue lines inside quotes. In the second example the backslashes are actively harmful, because inside single quotes they will be kept as such, thus making the string syntactically invalid. Just get rid of the backslashes and it will work.

Answer (score 3):

In

```
var="foo\
bar"
```

The sequence `\<newline>` is special inside double quotes, but not inside single quotes and is *removed*, so `$var` contains `foobar`.

When you're doing:

```
echo $json
```

You're using the split+glob operator (implicit operator invoked when you forget to quote an expansion), that is, the content of `$json` is split on the characters in `$IFS` and each word is subject to filename generation (aka globbing).

The default value of `$IFS` contains space tab and newline (and space, tab and newline also happen to be getting a special treatment with regards to splitting in that any sequence of them counts like one and leading and trailing ones are ignored). So for instance in:

```
var='  foo  *
bar'

echo $var
```

`$var` is first split into `foo`, `*` and `bar` (the *split* part) and `*` is expanded to the list of non-hidden files in the current directory (the *glob* part).

If you wanted to display the content as-is (but note that many `echo` implementations may mangle the content), you'd write:

```
$ echo "$json"
[     {         "count": 3     } ]
```

Now, if your intent is to compress the spacing, maybe you can use the split+glob operator to your advantage.

```
json='
  [
    {
      "count": 3
    }
  ]'

unset -v IFS # make sure we get a default splitting behaviour.
             # an unset -v IFS is equivalent to IFS=$' \t\n'
set -o noglob # disable the glob part

echo $json # use the split+glob operator
```

`echo` outputs its arguments separated by spaces so every sequence of space, tab or newline character will in effect be replaced by a single space character (except the leading and trailing ones which will be removed, and `echo` adds one newline character in the end). So you'll get:

```
[ { "count": 3 } ]
```

In any case, that won't discriminate whether the blanks are within quotes or not, so it may change the meaning of the json data (`"foo  bar"` would be transformed to `"foo bar"` for instance).

If you want to use the `\<newline>` sequence to escape (remove) the newline characters but otherwise keep the other blank characters while not have to escape the double quote characters, you could use a here-document:

```
json=$(cat <<EOF
  [\
    {\
      "count": 3\
    }\
  ]
EOF
)
echo "$json"
```

Which would give:

```
  [    {      "count": 3    }  ]
```

(the newlines have been removed (you could have chosen to preserve some of them by not prepending them with a backslash) but the other blank characters have been left untouched).